# Why total stereoisomers is 1 even if no geometrical isomers and optical-isomers are present

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, coordination-compounds, isomers, stereochemistry

Let's for example take the complex  structure type $\ce{MA_6}$, What will be the Total number of Stereo-isomers (=[Geometrical-isomers]+[optical-isomers]).

My effort was that There will be no G.I and O.I present in this octahedral structure. So there should be 0 (zero) stereoisomers.

But the correct answer is that total stereoisomers are 1 (one), but the total G.I and O.I are same (i.e 0).

I want to ask the reason for this.

Answer (score 2):

The equations you use *assume* $\ce{MA6}$ as the *first form* to join the atoms in a molecule/a complex as the first isomer to count.  Consider this first form of spatial arrangement as a reference.

Depending on the atoms at disposition, their number, their chemistry (in case of ligands, for example, their [denticity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Denticity)) there may be *additional possibilities* to arrange *all* these atoms in a molecule/a complex.  In a pairwise comparison of the first form, these may be e.g., an enantiomer, or a constitutional isomer.  So you add them up and report the total.